# Specflow .NET - disable xUnit multithreading for one feature

Tags: c#, multithreading, specflow, xunit

I have kind of twisted story here.

I have many BDD SpecFlow tests running in my solution on enterprise project.

There are some options in xUnit configuration, to disable threading in tests project, but I don't want to disable it for entire project.

Only one feature file and its' scenarios must be ran consequently and apart from others. (the test is simulating some system environment changes and it messes up while running with other tests).

Is there any simple solution for this?
None of available hooks allow to do that as well

*...or I just didn't see that possibility to create a workaround there.*

Answer (score 0):

For every feature- File there is a code behind file (.feature.cs) generated, which contains the test class. It is marked as partial.
So you can extend the generated test class and put there the needed XUnit attributes.